# AWS ECS Spring Boot Task killed and restarted on background work

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a Spring Boot web application running on AWS ECS service on Fargate with a desired count of 1.  It's configured with a LB in front for SSL termination and healthchecks.

Each night via `@scheduled` I run a batch job that does some recalculations.  At various points either during or shortly after that job runs my task is killed and a new one is spun up.  During the task running I notice a few things:

- CPU on the service (via cloud watch) spikes to above 60%
- My health checks from the load balancer still respond in a good amount of time
- There are no errors in my spring boot logs
- In the ECS service events I see `service sname-app-lb deregistered 1 targets in target-group ecs-sname-app-lb`

I'm trying to figure out how to tell exactly why the task is being killed.  Any tips on how to debug / fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned that you are running scheduled task? but you are expecting service health check?

Comment: It's not a scheduled task in the ECS sense, its just a `@scheduled` method in spring boot.

Comment: @gunygoogoo when the task is killed, and you go to stopped container on ECS and do you see any reason on why task is killed?

Answer (score 0):

So, i have have similar experience in the past. This is what you need to do:

```
1. Make sure you are streaming the application logs to the cloudwatch using the awslogs driver in the task definition (if you are not doing it already).
2. Put a delay in the app as a catch/handler wherever it can fail. This delay will make sure that the application logs are sent to cw logs the event of an exception, and thus prevent an abrupt exit of the task.
```

I initially thought as a fargate issue, but the above really help understand the underlying issue. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Spring application inside Docker in AWS Fargate, if it hits the memory limit, your application could get killed.

More information: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/